# FROM_TZ equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert this to work in PostgreSQL?

```
TO_CHAR(CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(columnname AS TIMESTAMP), 'GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' AS DATE),'MM/DD/YY HH:MI AM') AS dt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testdb=# select TO_CHAR(CAST('2020-02-28T18:43' AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern','MM/DD/YY HH:MI AM') as dt;                                                                                                                                          
        dt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-------------------
 02/28/20 01:43 PM
(1 row)
```

To make it clear what's going on, we'll start with the cast to TIMESTAMP, show that adding the first `AT TIME ZONE` makes it a tz-aware timestamp, and then how the 2nd does the timezone conversion.

```
testdb=# select CAST('2020-02-28T18:43' AS TIMESTAMP),
testdb-# CAST('2020-02-28T18:43' AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT',
testdb-# CAST('2020-02-28T18:43' AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern';
      timestamp      |        timezone        |      timezone       
---------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 2020-02-28 18:43:00 | 2020-02-28 18:43:00+00 | 2020-02-28 13:43:00
(1 row)
```

See the [timezone conversion docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working exactly how I expected!